# Copy html to clipboard (Angular)

Tags: angular, clipboard

Is there a way to copy html to clipboard in Angular?

I'm using ngx-clipboard, and trying to format the copied text (i.e., use bold, bullets)

.ts

```
constructor(private _clipboardService: ClipboardService) {}

callServiceToCopy() {
    this._clipboardService.copyFromContent('<B>This is an important message<\/B>\n These are the details');
}
```

Component:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="callServiceToCopy()">Copy</button>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ar12tp-irzz84

Comment: What do you mean by _format the copied text_ ? In your stackblitz example `callServiceToCopy()` function is working fine. I click on the button and the string was copied to my clipboard. Can you please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 2):

you can now use this api:

```
const type = "text/html";
const blob = new Blob([ '<h1>Your <b>html</b> content here</h1>' ], { type });
const data = [new ClipboardItem({ [type]: blob })];

navigator.clipboard.write(data);
```

Details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write

Check here for browser compatibility: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_clipboard_write

Answer (score 0):

```
copyToClipboard(id:string): void {
           const from = document.getElementById(id);
           const range = document.createRange();
           window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
           range.selectNode(from);
           window.getSelection().addRange(range);
           document.execCommand('copy');
           window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
 }

 <button (click)="copyToClipboard('<B>This is an important message<\/B>\n These are the details')">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: Thanks...that does not seem to work though.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ar12tp-5b4xua

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't use angular functionality, but here's what I use:

```
var dummy = document.createElement('input'),
  text = window.location.href;

document.body.appendChild(dummy);
dummy.value = text;
dummy.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
document.body.removeChild(dummy);
```

Comment: Thanks, but looking for angular response.

Answer (score 0):

## .html

```
<div id="infoEd" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" tabindex="2" contenteditable="true" (keyup)="" (keydown)="" (paste)="wrapContent($event)">
      </div>
```

## .ts

```
   public wrapContent(evt) {
      const pastedData = evt.clipboardData.getData('html');
        console.log(pastedData);
    }
```

This Stackoverflow answer can help:-  [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**app.component.ts:**

```
copyToClipboard(id:string): void {
  const fromHtml = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(id).innerHTML;
  const newNode = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  this.renderer.appendChild(this._elementRef.nativeElement, newNode);
  this.renderer.setProperty(newNode, 'innerHTML', fromHtml);
  this._clipboardService.copyFromContent(fromHtml);
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<textarea id="textId">This is a sample Text</textarea>
<button (click)="copyToClipboard('#textId')">Copy text</button>
```

Please check this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ar12tp-scrwbn